# Does order of operands in equality matter? (e.g. 1 == x vs x == 1)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

So I'm trying out the Google Closure Compiler and I've noticed that it switches all my equality parameters so that the variables are always on the right side of the comparison.

So now instead of `typeof XMLHttpRequest=="undefined"` I have `"undefined"==typeof XMLHttpRequest` and I have `if(null!==a)` instead of `if(a!==null)`, just as some examples.

I know they accomplish the same thing, but it's just not the style I'm used to. Is there some sort of benefit that you get for having these switched? I can't see how there would be.

Can someone explain to me *why the Closure Compiler decides to do this*? Is it just a preference of whoever wrote that part of Closure?

*Edit:* To clarify, people are telling me why it might be considered good coding practice. That's fine, but this is *after compilation*. Is there a performance benefit or is the Closure Compiler just trying to prove a point?

Comment: asked many times in different forms on SO

Comment: Ah, good ol' [Yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)...

Comment: Actually, this is **not** the same as the more general yoda condition question, please read the question carefully before answering/commenting/voting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler switches the order for a very simple reason: it compresses better with gzip.  The compiler doesn't care a wit about improving comprehension or making it easier to edit. By switching the order common comparisons such as "if (x == null) ... if (y == null) ..." become "if (null == x) ... if (null == y) ..."  Gzip finds "if (null ==" and is able to replace it with a single token.  It isn't a big improvement, but it adds up in a large code base.

Comment: That would make sense. I later read about `void 0` replacing `undefined` in the advanced optimizer mode purely for size/compression purposes. I'll mark this as the answer, although if you could actually show that gzip compresses better with the operands switched that would be even better!

Comment: @John can you provide a link or some more details? Sounds bizarre, but I'd love to learn more!

Comment: Here's the issue: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=461. Enhancements like this are tested on Google's code base (pretty much every major product such as maps and gmail).

Comment: @John3136 I don't know a lot about gzip, but upon reflection it makes sense that it would compress better if you had the code repeated across a large codebase. Consider the strings `typeof objectA=="undefined"` and `typeof objectB=="undefined"`, we'd need to compress 2 non-unique strings `typeof object` and `=="undefined"`. If you rearrange it, you can get that down to a single non-unique string `"undefined"==typeof object`.

Comment: @Nathan so from gzip POV it's more about the consistency than the actual order? That does make sense.

Comment: Exactly, it is a trying to build longer common strings.

Answer (score 12):

Commonly done in languages like C / C++ so you can't accidently do

```
if (a = null) {
    // sets a to null and everyone is happy.
    // but probably meant to check if a is null or not.
    // via (a == null)
}

if (null = a) {
    // won't compile
}
```

Comment: It's also used in Java to prevent throwing a NullPointerException in situations like this:  `"foo".equals(someString);`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that any decent compiler (or lint-style tool in case of a scripting language) will display a warning when using `if(a = null)` unless you explicitely state your intent by using `if((a = null))`

Comment: Hi John, I'm wondering if you could perhaps address the follow-up comment I made to alex's answer.

`Thanks for the answer, but I'm wondering why Closure does this. Closure compiles the code into this format, if there was a mistake like (a=1) in my original code, I'm sure Closure would probably just leave it there because (a=1) is still valid code. Why does it matter for compiled code to have the operands ordered in such a way? I don't think a sane coder would ever want to work on the compiled code again when they could refer to the source.`

Comment: Don't know enough about Closure to give a reliable answer, but: `if (1=a)` is not valid JS, and so the compiled code wouldn't run. You're more likely to find the bug than if you have `if (a=1)` which does run, but doesn't produce the correct results..

Comment: @John3136 thanks, I appreciate you getting back to me. It looks like the most plausible explanation is simply that gzip supposedly compresses better with the operands switched.

Comment: @Nathan - I'm no gzip expert either, but that doesn't make any sense to me at all! Got any links to where this info comes from? - I'm intrigued to know more!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can't assign to a constant, and `==` is easy to mistype (sometimes you may forget one, and use `=`).

For example, what's the difference between...

```
if (a == 1) { }
```

...and...

```
if (a = 1) { }
```

? The second one will always evaluate to *true*, not matter what the value of `a`.

If you flip the LHS and RHS, you can see the immediate benefit...

```
if (1 == a) { }
```

...will work as expected and...

```
if (1 = a) { }
```

...will fail, as you can't assign to a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm wondering why Closure does this. Closure compiles the code into this format, if there was a mistake like (a=1) in my original code, I'm sure Closure would probably just leave it there because (a=1) is still valid code. Why does it matter for compiled code to have the operands ordered in such a way? I don't think a sane coder would ever want to work on the compiled code again when they could refer to the source.

Answer (score 3):

The reason I know is is  done to prevent

```
if (x = 5) { }
```

If you reverse it to

```
if (5 = x) { }
```

You would get a compiler error.

But if you write it as

```
if (5 == x) { }
```

It will compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

My brain parses

```
if( x < y )
```

slightly faster than

```
if( y > x )
```

probably because real axis is always oriented from left to right, thus making condition easier to visualize.

However, in java it is more practical to write

```
if( "string".equals(x) ) {...
```

as opposed to "more natural"

```
if( x.equals("string") ) {...
```

to eliminate any opportunity for NPE.

Comment: It doesn't do any good to say *probably*. Do some benchmarks and find out.

Comment: @alex benchmarks on the human brain? I think that's what Tegiri was referring to. In the same way, my brain understands "x == 1" faster than it does "1 == x".

Comment: And programmer's mind is all that really matters -- because compilers can be fixed.

Comment: @Nathan Right, I didn't read the answer as thoroughly as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Just a cheap replacement of static analysis of particular case of common mistake/

Comment: So essentially you're saying the compiler is partially delinting the code first, even if that serves no purpose to the end result? That's plausible I guess, the lint utilities were probably done before the compiler.

Comment: I think so, cause in common case at low level value appears at proccessor's (or may be some kind interpretator alternative) register and is compared via opcode

Comment: For examlpe, you cannot make such mistake in c#, but you can in c++ or c